# Win8.1 Net Use Succeeds, Mapped Drive Fails

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, mapped-drive, net-use

A client has a nas box (nas01) and a batch script to connect three drives to it at startup.

```
net use h: \\nas01\home\Foo /user:Foo bar
net use m: \\nas01\music    /user:Foo bar
net use p: \\nas01\media    /user:Foo bar
```

From windows Explorer clicking on M and H drive gets him into the folders. P drive fails with a cross through it.

I opened a command prompt (`cmd`) as administrator (right click run as administrator) and ran the batch.

- It succeeded under CMD.
- It failed to let the user in under Windows Explorer.

I used `net use * /delete` from the CMD prompt then ran the following line manually.

```
net use p: \\nas01\media /user:Foo bar
```

In cmd I can do a `dir p:` and see the files, I can change to `p:` drive, change folders and see sub folders and files.  From Windows Explorer it get Nada.

A manual disconnect for each drive then re map of drives under windows explorer fixed the issue - all four drives accessible, but it leaves me with a batch file my client cant use when Windows drops the mapped drives again in the future.

Why is one side of windows (CMD) working but not useable under Windows Explorer? Any thoughts.

User has full admin rights on PC, local login, no UAC getting in the way.

Comment: Drives are mapped per logon. Opening cmd via "run as administrator" executes it in a different logon session from Explorer.

Comment: Thanks - good catch - however - I then tried it without run as - can dor a dir eof p drive in DOS / CMD but not in Windows Explorer. Just happened on a second windows 7 Pro PC yesterday.